# Parametric bit-width assignment in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synthesis

I would like to create a parametric bit-width assignment in Verilog.

Something like the following code:

```
module COUNTER
                    ( 
                        CLEAR,
                        CLK,
                        CODE)
#(parameter BUS_WIDTH   = 8)

reg [BUS_WIDTH-1:0] CODE;

always @(posedge CLK or posedge CLEAR)
begin
        if(CLEAR)
            begin
                CODE    <= BUS_WIDTH'b{BUS_WIDTH{0}};   
                CODEreg <= BUS_WIDTH'b{BUS_WIDTH{0}};
            end
    ...
```

What is the right way for it to be synthesizable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close.  The proper syntax is as follows:

```
            CODE    <= {BUS_WIDTH{1'b0}};  
            CODEreg <= {BUS_WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.12.1 *Replication operator*.

The one bit value (`1'b0`) is replicated 8 times to form the 8-bit value (`8'b0000_0000`).

This is synthesizable.

This is also called a *multiple concatenation*.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to do this unless you have linting tools and need to suppress warnings about mismatched sizes. Verilog implicitly pads or truncates expressions to the appropriate width.

```
if(CLEAR)
            begin
                CODE    <= 0;
                CODEreg <= 0;
            end
```

SystemVerilog has a *fill literal* `'0`, `'1`, `'z` that automatically replicates the value to the target expression

```
if(CLEAR)
            begin
                CODE    <= '0;   
                CODEreg <= '1;
            end
```